# Descendant selectors in php simple dom

Tags: php

http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm

PHP Simple dom descendant selection issue, consider the following html

```
<ul class="chunklist chunklist_set">

<li>
<a href="/test/php/book.calendar.html">Calendar</a> 

<ul class="chunklist chunklist_set chunklist_children">

<li><a href="/test/php/intro.calendar.html">Introduction</a></li>
<li><a href="/test/php/calendar.setup.html">Installing/Configuring</a></li>


<li>
<a href="/test/php/book.datetime.html">Date/Time</a> — Date and Time

<ul class="chunklist chunklist_set chunklist_children">
<li><a href="/test/php/intro.datetime.html">Introduction</a></li>
<li><a href="/test/php/datetime.setup.html">Installing/Configuring</a></li>


<li>
<a href="/test/php/book.hrtime.html">HRTime</a> — High resolution timing

<ul class="chunklist chunklist_set chunklist_children">
<li><a href="/test/php/intro.hrtime.html">Introduction</a></li>
<li><a href="/test/php/hrtime.setup.html">Installing/Configuring</a></li>
</ul>

</li>

</ul>
```

I am trying to group the selections as per the html code above. Here is where i get stuck im my php:

```
foreach ($html->find('ul.chunklist ul.chunklist_set') as $ul) {  // $html accepts mixed classes

    $links[] = $ul->find('li a')->href;  // now I have the correct array to work with

    foreach ($ul->find('li') as $li) {

        //$nulinks[] = $li->find('a')->href ;

        foreach ($li->find('a') as $a) {

            //$filtlinks[] = $a->href ;
        }
    }       
}
```

My $links array spits out:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 
    [1] => 
    [2] => 
)
```

Any ideas guys?

Pretty sure the same selectors would apply to jquery, if that gives anyone a clue how to deal with this bit of tricky html

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
if(!empty($html)){      
    foreach($html->find('ul') as $ul) {        
        $testul[] =  $ul->outertext;
    }
}

$result = key(array_splice( $testul, 0, 2 ));

unset($ul);

echo '<pre>',print_r($testul[2], 1),'</pre>';
```